# Rewriting arguments using quantifiers, variables, and predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

There are two statements which sounds similar to me but their answers are different according to answer sheet.

1. All birds can fly

Answer: ∀ x [B(x) → F(x)]

2. Some men are genius

Answer: ∃ x [M(x) ^ G(x)]

In the first part implication is used but in second part AND is used. There is no mention of 'if then' or 'And' in  statements so why the answers are different for similar sounding statements?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the system you're studying (first-order logic), a language has a fixed "universe" (also called a "domain of discourse"), and the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ always range over (i.e. "apply to") *all* the objects in that universe.

If the universe is just birds (i.e. if our language is only for talking about birds and nothing else), then "all birds can fly" can be written as just $\forall x F(x)$, since the "birds" part is built into the $\forall$. Similarly, if the universe is just men (sad!), then "some men are genius" can be written as $\exists x G(x)$. However, if we want write both statements in the same language, then the domain of discourse needs to include both men and birds, so we think of the universe as just "objects" and introduce predicates $B$ and $M$ to identify the birds and men. The quantifiers of this language range over *all objects*.

It's fairly clear that "some men are genius" is equivalent to "there exists an object that is a man and is genius", so we can write it as $\exists x (M(x)\land G(x))$. "All birds can fly" is trickier: we want to say something about just birds, but $\forall$ is going to give us a statement about all *objects*. To make this work, we need a formula inside the $\forall$ **that says $F(x)$ if $x$ is a bird but says nothing extra about $x$ if $x$ is not a bird**. You should convince yourself that such a formula is $\lnot B(x)\lor F(x)$, which is equivalent to $B(x)\to F(x)$ by the definitions of the logical symbols. We think of $\forall x (B(x)\to F(x))$ as saying "for every object x, if x is a bird, then x can fly", and it works because $B(x)\to F(x)$ is true when $x$ is not a bird.

Comment: If the statement is something like 'All men are genius', then can I write 'x is man implies x is genius'? In this case it will mean that if there is a man than he is genius. Some other x can be genius too. Right?

Comment: That's right. If your statement starts with "$M(x)\to$", then it effectively says nothing about x if x is not a man. And don't forget the $\forall x$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to look at this. In the first statement
about birds that can fly, the implication, B->F, just as any
other implication can be written as F or -B, or else,
-(B and -F). In the second statement about men geniuses,
it concerns the existence of a man who is a genius. It is
the same as stating that there is a genius who is a man.
Here, being a man and being a genius have symmetric roles.
In the first statement, being a bird and flying do not
have symmetric roles and implication is not symmetric.
For example, a single flying insect would invalidate
the statement that all flying things are birds.